# How to find the size of diff objects when executing 'git fetch'?

Tags: git

When executing `git fetch`, how can I know the exact size of objects/changes that will transfer from remote to local?

Comment: I think nobody's ever taught git to do that.  Why care? either you need the history or you don't.

Comment: @jthill I'm developing a update script for non-technical guys and they have network problems... If the size of changes is too large(100Mb+), it's hardly possible for them to update directly. So I need to add something like a proxy switch, which is turned on if size of changes is too big.

Answer (score 2):

The actual network traffic size depends on what you have locally, what the remote is going to give you, and what protocol you use to transport the data.

See the [Pro Git book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-Transfer-Protocols) for more details, but the short version is that if you use a "smart" protocol (`git://...` or `ssh://...`) to fetch, you can get a "thin pack" containing delta-compressed data representing repository objects that you currently lack, but compressed against objects that you have, that you have asked for in the `fetch`.  If you use a "dumb" protocol you can't get that, and you get either loose objects (bzip2 compressed) or "thick" packs.

Just looking at the (uncompressed) size of the objects themselves may not tell you much.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure if this is correct, and there is probably a much better way of doing this, but you could try:

```
git fetch --dry-run
```

This should show what the fetch would do without actually going ahead with it. If you have applicable remote changes, this information should be presented to you, for example:

```
(SHA1)..(SHA2)  master -> origin/master
```

Then you can use the `cat-file` with the size flag to inspect the commit, which I believe should represent the incoming changes you want:

```
git cat-file -s (SHA2)
```

The quantity returned is in bytes. I hope that might help you.